# Significant platform change, should a new tag be created? [ServiceStack]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Recently the REST platform ServiceStack went from being an [OpenSource project in v3](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3) to being a [Commercial solution in v4](http://servicestack.net).

The changes between v3 and v4 are significant, [breaking changes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes#whats-new-in-v4).

The problem is that many people aren't aware that platform went commercial - and has breaking changes. They follow tutorials from other sites and code currently found on SO, that references v3. They run the NUGET command that now installs v4 and things don't work for them.

As time goes on more answers are going to come in for ServiceStack v4 that don't apply to v3. And it will be difficult to separate what answers are relevant for what platform.

Also as v3 remains OpenSource it will continue to have many people using it where they don't need the commercial features.

Can separate tags be created to avoid this confusion? Re-tag current [servicestack](/questions/tagged/servicestack) as [servicestack-v3](/questions/tagged/servicestack-v3)?

---

To address concerns with v2 and v1:

I believe, legacy version were not supported, or maintained by the project owner. The project owner, @Mythz, voluntarily renamed ServiceStack to ServiceStackV3 to cover all legacy BSD releases. v3 is the most significant BSD release.

Alternatively a tag could be created as [servicestack-bsd](/questions/tagged/servicestack-bsd) or [servicestack-opensource](/questions/tagged/servicestack-opensource) to remove the explicit need for version. Thus v1 - v3 would be covered, and v4+ would just be [servicestack](/questions/tagged/servicestack)?

---

ServiceStack documentation recommends using `#servicestack-v3` hashtag in the question body. But of course this doesn't cover existing legacy questions. Nor will everybody actually include this hashtag. *(I myself only just found this recommendation)*

> Whilst there is no official direct or commercial support for the legacy v3 releases, StackOverflow remains the optimal place to ask for support. Please also include the **#servicestack-v3** hashtag when Asking a new question.

Comment: What about v2 and v1? (I'm not familiar with the platform)

Comment: @Stijn Legacy version were not supported, or maintained by the project owner. The project owner, Mythz, voluntarily renamed ServiceStack to ServiceStackV3 for the legacy BSD release. v3 is the most significant BSD release. [github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3)

Comment: So ServiceStack is telling people to use *hashtags* on Stack Overflow? *What are they thinking?*

Comment: @Scott What I mean is you can't just retag everything to v3 without being sure that the question is about v3. For example, v2.92.0 was [released](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/2.92.0) on 2011-06-12 while the [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657087/system-badimageformatexception-on-running-servicestack-examples) on Stack Overflow about ServiceStack was posted on 2011-01-11

Comment: @Stijn I appreciate that. I updated my question to say this could be addressed then using [tag:servicestack-bsd] or [tag:servicestack-opensource].